# Android: Анимация при отрисовке Bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-canvas

Есть SurfaceView с отрисокой изображений onDraw(). Все работает отлично, подскажите как выполнить анимацию этого bitmap на канвасе.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.ground);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null, rectGround,null);
}
```

Например, такая анимация не отрабатывает:

```
Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(CONTEXT.getResources(), angry);
Drawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(CONTEXT.getResources(), angry2);
AnimationDrawable mAnim = new AnimationDrawable();
mAnim.addFrame(d1, 100);
mAnim.addFrame(d2, 100);
mAnim.draw(canvas);
mAnim.start();
```

Comment: не понятен вопрос: в onDraw вы и так рисуете на Canvas

Comment: вопрос - как анимировать битмап?

Comment: 1 bitmap или серию кадров? что вы хотите с ним делать?

Comment: @Style-7, хочу разобраться как анимировать объекты. Начал с одного объекта, если вы можете подсказать как сделать анимацию одного битмапа или даже серии, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: тонны ссылок и литературы http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/frameanimation.php

Comment: там не показана анимация на канвасе, только внутри ImageView. Это не интересно

Comment: появился новый объект вопроса ImageView - с него надо было начинать: создаете Canvas выбираете в него Bitmap от ImageView, рисуете обновляете ImageView через invalidate.